# Помогите новичку

Tags: map, java

Доброе время суток!

Телефонная книга. Консольная программа. При запуске выводит следующее:

> Telephone Book
>
> To list all records enter 1
>
> To find tel by name enter 2
>
> To add new record enter 3
>
> To delete record enter 4
>
> To exit enter 0
>
> What to do? >
>
> Цитата

Далее программа ожидает ввода числа и в зависимости от него выполняет
соответствующее действие, а затем снова выводит меню. Работает до тех пор, пока 
пользователь не введет 0, в этом случае программа завершается.

1 - Выводит все записи в формате: Имя - Телефон

2 - Просит ввести имя, затем выводит телефон по имени, либо сообщение о том, что 
такого имени не найдено.

3 - Запрашивает на ввод сначала имя, потом телефон и сохраняет данные.

4 - Запрашивает на ввод имя, а затем удаляет запись, если находит ее по имени.

При реализации сделать свой класс `TelephoneBook`, в котором и будет вся логика работы. Для хранения записей использовать `HashMap<String, String>`. Что-то я застрял вот на этом (но классы создал для методов)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Phone Book");
    System.out.println("To list all records enter 1");
    System.out.println("To find tel by name enter 2");
    System.out.println("To add new record enter 3");
    System.out.println("To exit enter 0");
    System.out.print("What to do? > ");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int n = input.nextInt();

    if(n == 0){

    }
    else if (n==1){

    }

    else if (n==2){

    }
    else if (n==3){

    }

        }

}
```

Также получилось класс показать, вариант №1.  но как правильно записать его в IF?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Show {

public static void show() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("pb.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    String strLine;

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              System.out.println (strLine);
    }
    br.close();
}
}
```

Comment: А в чем конкретные вопросы? Или нужно что бы кто-то домашку сделал?

Comment: вопрос по реализации.. как это сделать... но я понял суть... делаю через свич..

Answer (score 1):

Для чего вам класс Show?
В задании же явно сказано использовать [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
Судя по заданию №2 ключем будет имя, а значением номер телефона.

Comment: тут еще можно поспорить что правильно должно быть ключем... считаю что номер, так как на ФИО номер еще можно добавить, а на номер второе ФИО нет

Comment: @Alext, ну почему же нельзя?

Это Вы в коммуналках не жили...

--

Реально для такой задачи нужны мультимап для имен (учитывая однофамильцев) и мап для номеров.

ФИО -> список номеров

номер -> список фамилий

И естественно, методы должны обеспечивать консистентность всех списков.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам класс Show? Вставьте метод `show` в `TelephoneBook` и вызывайте "as-is":

```
else if (n==1){ show() }
```

Если так уж вам не терпится использовать именно класс `Show` то статический метод `show()` вызывается просто как `Show.show()`

Comment: да спасибо, это сделал.. но постоянно выскакивает Эксепшен...